# Why i can't call this function from my main activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

This Function is in a separate .kt file in my android studio compose project.

Has this to do something with the OptIn marker? Since all other functions which don't have this OptIn marker are working.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalWearMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun SwipeDetector(): Swiped? {
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate more *Why I can't call this function*? Do you get Exception and if yes, can you share the stacktrace? And also the function you provided is not completed.

Comment: The only error i get is this:

Unresolved reference: SwipeDetector.

The Function is in a separate kotlin file and i want call this function from the main activity.

other functions are callable.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it sounds like you are dealing with a [required opt in](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/opt-in-requirements.html#require-opt-in-for-api).
This means if a function calls another function that has the required `OptIn` annotation, this function needs to opt in as well. This can be solved by annotating the calling function `OptIn` as well, or marking the class in which the function as `OptIn`, or marking the whole file as `OptIn`.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalWearMaterialApi::class)
fun callingSwipeDetector(…

//or the whole class
@OptIn(ExperimentalWearMaterialApi::class)
class ContainingFunctionCallingSwipeDetector…

//or on top of the file that contains the function
@file:OptIn(ExperimentalWearMaterialApi::class)
```

Comment: sry still get the same error:

Unresolved reference: SwipeDetector.

Comment: then you have to import the function in the place where you use it: `import package.function`